# Conditional bold in sap.m.Text object

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have this code in a controller file to bind items to a table:

```
        oTable.bindAggregation("items", {
            path: sRelPath,
            template: new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
                cells: [
                    new sap.m.Text({
                        text: {
                            path: 'relationship_type',
                            formatter: this.formatter.textBold
                        },
                        id: "relTypeText"
                    }),
                    new sap.m.Text({
                        text: "{client_name}",
                        id: "relClientName"
                    })
                ]
            }),
```

I am trying to format the 'relationship_type' value as bold if it returned with a certain string of text in it. I am using this formatter:

```
     textBold: function(sText) {
        if (typeof sText === "string" && sText.indexOf("(Self)") > -1) {
            //return $("#relTypeText").html("<b>"+sText+"</b>");
            return sText.bold();
        }
        return sText;
     },
```

Using this method, the text is returned in the table column as `<b>Text</b>`, as opposed to **Text**. I commented out the jQuery, as that returns the [object Object] reference.

I'm sure it's something simple. I know I can use sap.m.Label in an xml view and use the 'design' parameter, but I am binding the items in the controller in this instance. I tried using sap.m.Label in the controller instead, but same result.

Is it possible to append a property to a control element if a certain condition matches? As in, if I used sap.m.Label, could I append the 'design: Bold' property using the formatter? I am unclear on the correct syntax of doing something like that.

Any help is appreciated!

** Update **

As per @Sid 's recommendations, I implemented the following code in my formatter:

```
     textBold: function(sText) {
        if (typeof sText === "string") {
            if (sText.indexOf("(Self)") > -1) {
                this.setDesign("Bold");
            } 
        }
        return sText;
     },
```

Which returned this on the front end:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial suggestion is that if you are allowed to then use Label and LabelDesign as follows inside your formatter:

```
<Ref. to label>.setDesign(sap.m.LabelDesign.Bold)
```

or using an expression binding based on value of 'relationship_type'.

Alternative: I believe the issue is that you are attempting to use a formatter to return HTML code. In SAPUI5, formatter functions work on the values passed from the model binding and return a format to apply on to the generated HTML code. They will apply style classes to the bound value and are not generally supposed return an HTML element.

> Is it possible to append a property to a control element if a certain condition matches?

Yes. It is possible. Another approach suitable to your needs here is to add a Style Class to the element in question. In this case the first Text field.

```
<Controller Reference>.getView().byId("id of your element").addStyleClass("myboldclass")
```

where "myboldclass" is the one containing your required formatting

> As in, if I used sap.m.Label, could I append the 'design: Bold' property using the formatter?

Please see the initial suggestion using Label Design with formatters or expression binding.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Yes, @Sid, it does, thanks. I updated the post above so you can see my final code. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

you can define a style like following in your CSS.

```
.boldText {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Also you define your formatter function :

```js
textBold: function(sText) {
            if(sText.indexOf("(Self)") > -1) {
               this.addStyleClass("boldText"); //this refers to the Text control
            }
            return sText;
        };
```

You can check this working [example](http://jsbin.com/qadaxebowa/edit?html,css,output).

Thank you.